# Enviar correo con PHPMailer personalizado

Tags: php

Tengo un script que manda email a los correos que extrae de una consulta. Pero cuando son dos correos o mas, los que devuelve la consulta, mi script manda un email a todos los correos, no manda un email personalizado a cada uno.

En el email que llega a los usuarios, en el lugar donde pone:

```
Para:...
```

Ahí me salen todos los correos a los que se les ha mandado el mensaje pero no quiero que salgan

¿Alguna ayuda?

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, "select email from usuarios");

  $mail=new PHPMailer();
  $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

  $body = 'Correo de prueba';

  $mail->IsSMTP();
  $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';
  $mail->Port       = 587;
  $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
  $mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;
  $mail->Username = 'micorreo@gmail.com';
  $mail->Password = '******';
  $mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;

  $mail->From = 'micorreo@gmail.com';
  $mail->FromName = 'Nombre';
  $mail->addReplyTo('micorreo@gmail.com', 'Information');
  $mail->Subject    = 'Correo de prueba';
  $mail->MsgHTML($body);

  while ($extraido= mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      $mail->AddAddress($extraido['email']);
  };
  $mail->send();
  mysqli_close($link);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  $result = mysqli_query($link, "select email from usuarios");

  while ($extraido= mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $mail=new PHPMailer();
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

    $body = 'Correo de prueba';

    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port       = 587;
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
    $mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;
    $mail->Username = 'micorreo@gmail.com';
    $mail->Password = '******';
    $mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;

    $mail->From = 'micorreo@gmail.com';
    $mail->FromName = 'Nombre';
    $mail->addReplyTo('micorreo@gmail.com', 'Information');
    $mail->Subject    = 'Correo de prueba';
    $mail->MsgHTML($body);

    $mail->AddAddress($extraido['email']);

    $mail->send();
  };

  mysqli_close($link);
```

Con algo como esto debería de valerte. Instanciar el objeto `PHPMailer` por cada uno de los usuarios a los que se les desea enviar el email.

Comment: Excatamente eso es lo que quería! Muchisimas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

primero deberías obtener los correos y nombres con tu consulta y por cada usuario obtenido, llamar a la función que envía un correo. Es decir:

```
/* Función para enviar correos */
function enviarMail($nombre,$email){
    $mail   = new PHPMailer;
    .... 
    ....
    $mail->addAddress($email, $nombre); 
    ....
    $mail->send()   
}

 /* Obtención de correos */
foreach($crud->ListarUsuarios() as $r):     

    enviarMail($r->__GET('Nombre'),$r->__GET('Correo')); // llamas a enviarMail()

endforeach;
```

Como usas mysqli_query con un While, sería más o menos así:

```
  $result = mysqli_query($link, "select email,nombre from usuarios");

  while ($extraido= mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {  

      $mail=new PHPMailer();
      $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

      $body = 'Correo de prueba';

      $mail->IsSMTP();
      $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';
      $mail->Port       = 587;
      $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
      $mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;
      $mail->Username = 'micorreo@gmail.com';
      $mail->Password = '******';
      $mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;

      $mail->From = 'micorreo@gmail.com';
      $mail->FromName = 'Nombre';
      $mail->addReplyTo('micorreo@gmail.com', 'Information');
      $mail->Subject    = 'Correo de prueba';
      $mail->MsgHTML($body);
      $mail->addAddress($extraido['email'], $extraido['nombre']); 
      $mail->Body    = 'Hola:'.$nombre.'<br> este es un correo de prueba'
      $mail->send();

  };

  mysqli_close($link);
```

**Ojo** no lo copies y pegues por que no se si hay algún error al usarlo de esta forma. Pero te da una idea de cómo implementarlo. Lo principal es que debes instanciar todas las clases de PHPMailer para enviar cada correo no solo $mail->AddAddress().

Comment: También he probado esta forma, y funciona! Gracias!